# Using Backbone.js along with rails, and JSON file as model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

I am new to both rails and backbone, and I need help to figure out how do go about creating an app.  I am trying to create a rails app that could read the contents of provided JSON file and perform the required action mention in the JSON file. My application will not have any database but JSON will act as a database (that's my current thought). AS there is no database I am confused about how to use rails model for reading JSON? Should I use rails model or should I use backbone's model to read JSON?

Comment: I think you're mixing up a LOT of concepts here..

Comment: @Noli yeah, I guess you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what exactly you are trying to implement. 
It seems that you are trying to build a JSON RPC implementation and using an existing rpc backend will save a lot of work for you. The following link might be informative : http://json-rpc.org/

Also I do not understand that how do you plan to implement persistence without a database backend. In case the application does not require persistence the model layer is simply not required. Are you very sure that an MVC framework actually suits your requirements. It does not seem to fit in.